# What does "W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@eb23963" mean?

Tags: android, android-activity

When I press a button to change to another activity i get this: "W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@eb23963"

Even with the android sample: https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-fundamentals-apps-v2/tree/master/TwoActivities/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/twoactivities

Why?

Comment: Looking at the source code of  [ActivityThread](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java)  .I see that it gets thrown when ActivityClientRecord isn't found in the list of mActivies. So this is where the warning is being called. I haven't been able to find out why yet.

Comment: Yep, i don't know why. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check for any infinite loop in your Second Activity where you want to go on Button Click.

I was facing the same issue with rewardVideoAd:

> Before:

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        //Demo ad
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        if (ad.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            ad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
    else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Ad Already loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

> After

```
private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    if (!mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
        //Demo ad
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        if (ad.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            ad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        //loadRewardedVideoAd(); // I removed this line
    }
    else {
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Ad Already loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Hope it helps!!